# Python print statement for Histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, histogram

Alright so for midterm review, this was one problem I needed to solve:

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Design and implement an application that creates 100 random positive integers of values in the range 1 to 100 and then creates a chart showing how often the values appeared. The chart should look like the one shown here. It shows how many values fell in the range 1 to 10, 11 to 12, and so on. Print one asterisk for each value entered.

Notes: 
a.  You must use a list
b.  Do not use if statements

Example Below:

```
1  - 10   | ****
11 - 20   | **
21 - 30   | ****************
31 - 40   | 
41 - 50   | ***
51 - 60   | ********
61 - 70   | ****************
71 - 80   | *****
81 - 90   | *
91 - 100  | ***
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Anyways, this is my code so far:

```
import random
frequency = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for roll in range( 1,101 ):
    face = random.randrange( 1, 100  )
    frequency[face%10] += 1
    print(frequency)

for i in range( len( frequency ) ):
    print("%7d%5d %-s" % ((i+1,frequency[i], "*" * frequency[i])))
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

When I print, this is what I get:

```
[8, 12, 8, 12, 12, 9, 9, 11, 9, 10]
  1    8 ********
  2   12 ************
  3    8 ********
  4   12 ************
  5   12 ************
  6    9 *********
  7    9 *********
  8   11 ***********
  9    9 *********
 10   10 **********
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

My program runs right, but my problematic code is this part:

```
print("%7d%5d %-s" % ((i+1,frequency[i], "*" * frequency[i])))
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

My problem is that I don't get how to do the 1 - 10 , 11-20, etc. part seen in the original example. All I know how to do is make it count upwards(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 etc.)

Help?

Answer (score 0):

So you have for `i in range(something)` and then you have `print i+1` and you get `1,2,3,...` but you want to get `1-10,11-20,21-30,...` right? So then `print i*10+1,"-",(i+1)*10` should give you what you want.

Comment: No, I want to get 1-10, 11-20, 21-30, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost close, just try this way:

```
import random
frequency = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for roll in range( 1,101 ):
    face = random.randrange( 1, 100  )
    frequency[face%10] += 1

print(frequency)

for i in range(len(frequency)):
   print("%7d-%2d %5d %-s" % ((i*10+1,(i+1)*10,frequency[i], "*" * frequency[i])))
```

Add one more number in last line.It's just small math trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `/` than `%` in

```
frequency[face%10] + 1
```

Then face value 1~10 will make

`frequency[0] += 1`

So, first item of frequency array means 1-10

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're close and you only need a couple changes...:

```
import random
frequency = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
for roll in range( 1,101 ):
    face = random.randrange( 1, 100  )
    frequency[face // 10] += 1
print(frequency)

for i in range( len( frequency ) ):
    print("%2d - %3d %5d %-s" %
         (((10*i+1, 10*i+10, frequency[i], "*" * frequency[i]))))
```

I'm using `face // 10` (truncating division) where you used `face % 10` (modulus) that makes little sense, and slightly changing the formatting in the final `print` -- staying as close to your code as feasible.

I think there are better ways but this one is good enough and, as we all know (or should know:-), "good enough is good enough"!-)